# Large store database design in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database, database-design, laravel-10

I have a Laravel store project that I am confused to develop my products database. My store products are clothes, shoes, pants, laptops, phones, headphones, etc.

Hello friends, good time
This database is for the products of my store:

[database photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIkpR.png)

But as long as I have products like shoes and clothes it works correctly and optimally because they have many options, for example these are the options for product_id=3 which is a dress in the product_options table:

| option::1 | option::2 | option::3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| color_id:8 | color_id:8 | color_id:9 |
| size_id: 3 | size_id:5 | size_id:5 |
| price: 25 | price: 20 | price: 20 |
| stock: 5 | stock: 9 | stock: 8 |

But for products such as phones, laptops, etc., which have only one option and do not have color_id and size_id at all. I don't know what to do. please help. For example, these are the options for product_id=5, which is a laptop in the product_options table:

| option::1 |
| --- |
| color_id:null |
| size_id: null |
| price: 50 |
| stock: 5 |

Comment: Why don't you simply put grey, black or something for the color, and size 6", 7" for phones or 15.6" or 17.3" for laptops?
Also, do you get the results where the color or size is null or you don't get the response?
The migrations needs to be better, I can give you an example of an ERA diagram a bit later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to only add options which the product requires, as well as having the possibility to add any type of options, you should redesign your database and use a "many to many" relationship.

1. Remove "color_id" and "size_id" from "products_options"
2. Rename "products_options" to "variations"
3. Remove "colors" and "sizes" tables
4. Create "options" table with fields : id, type
5. Create a pivot table named "options_variations" with fields: variation_id, option_id, value

Create all your options in the "options" table:

```
$option1 = new Option(['type'=>'color'])
$option2 = new Option(['type'=>'size'])
$option3 = new Option(['type'=>'screen_size'])
$option4 = new Option(['type'=>'battery_life'])
```

Create products:

```
$product1 = new Product(['title'=>'Dress 1'])
$product2 = new Product(['title'=>'Laptop 1'])
```

Create variations:

```
$variation1 = new Variation(['product_id'=>1, 'price'=>55])
$variation2 = new Variation(['product_id'=>2, 'price'=>1000])
```

And assign your options to the variation:

```
$variation1->attach($option1, ['value'=>'red'])
$variation1->attach($option2, ['value'=>'10'])
$variation2->attach($option4, ['value'=>'8h'])
```

You can read more about [Many to Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) and on how to [insert/update related models](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) on laravel.com. If you have a laracast subscription, you can watch https://laracasts.com/series/mysql-database-design/episodes/11.

Comment: how good are you!
thanks for every thing ❤️